# First print something before sending a file to the user

Tags: python, bottle

As it is now the following code cannot return a tuple, with 2 elements, 1st one being a astring and then a response method.

```
@app.route( '/file', methods=['POST'] )
def file():

    pdata = ''
    pdata = pdata + '''<img src="/static/img/arrow.gif" align="left">'''
    return pdata, send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )
```

What is the easiest way to have pdata print some lines before i return afile to the user?

I do NOT wish to create an extra html template just to print some lines.

Comment: How about a simple `print (stuff here)` before return?

Comment: If i try to 'print pdata' before return it does not print anything.

Comment: Print something where? In your server log? (`print` or `logger.error` will do that). Or to the browser?

Comment: I just want to print something in the brower, a simple messge to notify the user that he is about to receive the file

Comment: Okay, got it. Then I think you're misunderstanding how HTTP works. There is exactly one response for every request - you can't send two responses. (Note that you could probably do this with enough suitably advanced javascript, but that's quite complicated.)

Comment: You can send multiple responses with yield.

Answer (score 1):

Use yield.

```
@app.route( '/file', methods=['POST'] )
def file():

    pdata = ''
    pdata = pdata + '''<img src="/static/img/arrow.gif" align="left">'''
    yield pdata
    for f in send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True ):
        yield f
```

FULL EXAMPLE OF IT WORKING:

```
from bottle import app, get, post, template, route, run

@get('/file')
@post('/file')
def file():

    pdata = '<h3>Hello<h3>'
    pdata = pdata + '''<img src="/static/img/arrow.gif" align="left">'''
    yield pdata
    yield '<br><br>HELLO WORLD'

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: I just tried `# Prepare selected file for download...
 filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'
 yield pdata
 yield send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )

 return 'ok' ` but i'am receiving the error `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a generator.`

Comment: Your function is returning an iterator, use a for loop against the function and yield each result.

Comment: Honestly though, you should read some documentation, many of your questions are answered in the documentation.

Comment: i don't understand how you mean it. Use for where? if i'am to `yield` the pdata and send_from_directory what must the return statemnt be?

Comment: Could you please explain to me as simple as you can your suggestion? Here is the functionality i need to do: `filename = request.form.get('filename')
 filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

 yield send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )
 
 return pdata`

Comment: When i'm trying to run it i get `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a generator.` When i use yield i don't have to use return?

Comment: How am I supposed to know what your function send_from_directory is returning.  This is what is causing the issue.

Comment: If i replace `yield send_from_directory` with `return send_from_directory` it returns the file it works without error. Even if i just use `yield pdata` the same error appears, so its yield that is causing the issue.

Comment: I removed `send_from_directory` entirely and i just left `yield pdata` and i receive the exact error message. `pdata` only holds some html lines, nothing else.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  You have not provided sufficient code for me to test.  I posted an updated example of how it works, and confirmed it does.  If you need more assistance you need to provide a complete example.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'am using Flask, not Bottle and every time i try to `yield pdata` i get the error `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable The view function did not return a valid response.`

Comment: Your initial post is literally tagged with python and BOTTLE.

Comment: i don't know why but to me `yield` is not working at all. i cant even print a "Hello" with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your print can't output something, it may hooked by your framework.

You may try to print things in the following ways:

- use std.err

```
import sys
print(pdata, file=sys.stderr)
```

- logging module

```
import logging
logging.error(pdata)
```

Comment: What you mean by "hooked" by Bottle? Are you sure that from within a view function we can actually print a string before the return statement? I tried both way but nothing gets printed on browser or in the error_log.

Comment: Why the following statement of returning a tuple won't work? `return pdata, static_file( filename, root='/home/nikos/public_html/static/files' )` ?

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος I am not family with the framework you used, but what I mean is that if the print can not work, it may caused by your framework redirect ing the stdout. You can read the documentation of your framework for more details.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος If you just want to print something in your browers. You have to write the html  or js to the brower. One easy method is just put the debug information into html like `returned_html_str = '<script> alert(%s); </script>' % pdata`

Comment: Perhaps cna you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576913/ensure-that-values-are-passed-with-unicode-encoding

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος Try to use unicode to render your html template. Something like `template('.... {{filename}}', filename = filename.decode(your_locale_file_encoding))` in which `your_local_file_encoding` should be your locally file encoding. (In most case your should set it to be utf-8)

Comment: if you mean like this: `return template( 'files.html', authuser=auth.username, filename=filename.decode('utf-8') )` it errors out: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος Sorry, you are using py3. In py3, string is unicode by default, you don't need to convert the encoding. My suggestion is you may change the name of your file as just English letters, try to avoid the buggy encoding problem.

Comment: Since i'm using Python3 and its supposed to be unicode encoding why it has trouble downloading the file?

Comment: Please help me with this issue where i'm describing the probelm exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576913/generate-a-link-with-utf-8-values-and-passing-it-to-a-flask-route

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = request.form.get('filename')         # value comes from posted html form

# Prepare selected file for download...
if request.args:
    filename = request.args.get('filename')         # value comes from template link
    filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'

    return send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )

return render_template( 'files.html', authuser=auth.username, filename=filename )
```

I tried it as as above by sending the use to 'files.html' template so he can see the html data output and then from there i used:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="5; URL=http://superhost.gr/files/download?filename={{ filename }}">
```

so it can return in the same callback function to get the file.
This is what i can think of.

If someone has a more clear solution please let me know.